# setText not displaying the value to a TextView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Let me preface that I'm new to programming for Android. I've been doing my due diligence to research to no avail. I have the source code below and I'm having issues with returning the value for returning.

I have the code laid out on eclipse and it's not triggering any errors. But when I build the code below, it comes back with an error. After inspecting the values in debug view, I can see the proper values just not binded to the TextView.

```
public class MyFirstActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      calculateResult(2012, 9, 29);
  }
  private void calculateResult(int year, int month, int day) {
      long days = 0L;
      int returning = 0;

      java.util.Calendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day);

      long todayMI = new java.util.Date().getTime();
      long calMI = cal.getTimeInMillis();
      long millDiff = calMI - todayMI;

      if (millDiff < 0) {
            returning = 0;
      } else {
            days = millDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
            returning = (int) Math.ceil(days / 24f);
      }

      TextView days_int_remaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days_int_remaining);
      days_int_remaining.setText(returning);
  }
}
```

If it helps, here's the TextView on my layout XML:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/days_int_remaining"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:shadowColor="#5000"
      android:shadowDx="4"
      android:shadowDy="3"
      android:shadowRadius="1"
      android:textColor="#fff"
      android:textSize="70dip"
      android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

It may be something simple that I'm missing. Anything to help me further understand the code is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
TextView days_int_remaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days_int_remaining);
days_int_remaining.setText(String.valueOf(returning));
```

instead of

```
TextView days_int_remaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days_int_remaining);
days_int_remaining.setText(returning);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the error you get is "runtime-error - close application".

If you look at method `setText(...)` that is overloaded you will see that it takes arguments with `CharSequence` (this is probably what you want) and `int resId` (this is what you provide).

resId - will seek if there is an resource in `/values/strings.xml` with given `name` attribute.

The resolution is to provide `String`:

```
days_int_remaining.setText(String.valueOf(returning));
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn your `returning` int into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Basically you have to convert your int value to a string before calling setText();

```
public class MyFirstActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      TextView days_int_remaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days_int_remaining);
      int resultat = calculateResult(2012, 9, 29);
      days_int_remaining.setText(Integer.toString(resultat));
  }
  private int calculateResult(int year, int month, int day) {
      long days = 0L;
      int returning = 0;

      java.util.Calendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day);

      long todayMI = new java.util.Date().getTime();
      long calMI = cal.getTimeInMillis();
      long millDiff = calMI - todayMI;

      if (millDiff < 0) {
            returning = 0;
      } else {
            days = millDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
            returning = (int) Math.ceil(days / 24f);
      }

       return returning;

  }
}
```

Comment: He IS updating TextView on UI thread - invoking method doesn't change the running Thread. (after you've changed your response this comment is not longer valid)